# How to integrate mailChimp with php. What facility provided by mailchimp with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailchimp

I am using codeigniter framework to develop a website. I want to send mail to the registered user with mailchimp. I also want to know number of functions that provided by mailchimp with php like create Campaign add list add user to list etc.
I mean how can we use these functionality with php and mailchimp integration.

Comment: First you should start with Mailchimp [documentation](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/). PHP uses v2 API. Next would be checking Mailchimp PHP API on [github](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples). To start using it you would need composer, so find appropriate [tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) of "CodeIgniter+composer".

Comment: The MailChimp provided libraries are only for v2, which will be going away at the end of the year. MailChimp has, so far, been recommending people use plain HTTP libraries and their [v3 documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/).